# Indexed with data import handler an postgrel array integer

Tags: regex, solr

I'm trying to indexed a database which contain an array of int.

I've declared on solr schema that is multivalued fied.

I've used split option to delimited each value but impossible to use regex to eliminated the { and } at the end of array.

my db-config :

```
   <entity name="hut" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="select activities ,id from     app_huts_archives where is_latest_version = true and activities is not null">
    <field column="activities" regex="(\w*)" replaceWith="" splitBy=","  name="activity"  />
```

My current query result :

```
 <arr name="activity">
      **<str>{1</str>**
      <int>2</int>
      <int>3</int>
      <int>4</int>
      **<str>6}</str>**
    </arr>
```

Is my regex wrong or other ?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check on the regex solution.

Alternate Solution would be to use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to split, replace and generate multivalued fields

```
<dataConfig>
        <script><![CDATA[
                function retrieveRelativePath(row)    {
                    var activities= row.get('activities');
                    // replace and split activities and add as multivalued field
                    return row;
                }
        ]]></script>
        <document>
                <entity name="e" pk="id" transformer="script:retrieveRelativePath" query="select * from X">
                ....
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```